# Get Response using Json, when Some object not came that time app crash?

Tags: android, json

I am creating one model using my response, create model use JSOn. In response some parameter came some time and few are not came some time, my code given as under.
 1. Response

```
{
"result": {
"success": true,
"data": [
  {
    "uid": "xxxxxxx",
    "total_activities": "19",
    "points": 105,
    "guesstimated_reach": "39",
    "rank": 1,
    "bonus_points": {
      "details": [],
      "total_bonus_points": 0
    },
    "user_details": {
      "first_name": "Pauras More",
      "last_name": "!",
      "city": "Mumbai",
      "email": "xxxxxxx.com",
      "snetwork_influence": {
        "fb": {
          "friends": 11
        },
        "ln": {
          "connections": 116
        },
        "tw": {
          "friends": 50,
          "followers": 3,
          "listed": 18,
          "favorites": 224,
          "statuses": 1380
        }
      },
      "saccounts": {
        "fb": {
          "id": "xxxxxxx",
          "first_name": "xxxxxxx",
          "last_name": "xxxxxxx",
          "extra_data": {
            "timeline_album_id": "xxxxxxx"
          }
        },
        "ln": {
          "id": "xxxxxxx",
          "first_name": "xxxxxxx",
          "last_name": "xxxxxxx"
        },
        "tw": {
          "id": "xxxxxxx",
          "first_name": "xxxxxxx",
          "last_name": ""
        }
      },
      "pic": "xxxxxxx"
    }
  },
  {
    "uid": "xxxxxxx",
    "total_activities": "21",
    "points": 72,
    "guesstimated_reach": "100",
    "rank": 2,
    "bonus_points": {
      "details": [],
      "total_bonus_points": 0
    },
    "user_details": {
      "first_name": "xxxxxxx",
      "last_name": "T",
      "city": "xxxxxxx",
      "email": "xxxxxxx.com",
      "snetwork_influence": {
        "ln": {
          "connections": 19
        },
        "tw": {
          "friends": 0,
          "followers": 0,
          "listed": 0,
          "favorites": 0,
          "statuses": 0
        },
        "fb": {
          "friends": 527
        }
      },
      "saccounts": {
        "ln": {
          "id": "xxxxxxx",
          "first_name": "xxxxxxx",
          "last_name": "xxxxxxx"
        },
        "tw": {
          "id": "xxxxxxx",
          "first_name": "xxxxxxx",
          "last_name": ""
        },
        "ig": {
          "id": "xxxxxxx",
          "first_name": "xxxxxxx",
          "last_name": "",
          "username": "xxxxxxx"
        },
        "fb": {
          "id": "xxxxxxx",
          "first_name": "xxxxxxx",
          "last_name": "xxxxxxx",
          "extra_data": {
            "timeline_album_id": "xxxxxxx"
          }
        }
      },
      "pic": "xxxxxxx.jpg"
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

}

- My Model class is,

  ```
  public class SAccountConnectModel {
   /* Social Account name*/
  public String SAccount_facebook = "false";
  public String SAccount_linkedin = "false";
  public String SAccount_twitter = "false";
  public String SAccount_instagram = "false";
  public String SAccount_youtube = "false";

  public String getSAccount_facebook() {
  return SAccount_facebook;
  }

  public void setSAccount_facebook(String SAccount_facebook) {
  this.SAccount_facebook = SAccount_facebook;
  }

  public String getSAccount_linkedin() {
  return SAccount_linkedin;
  }

  public void setSAccount_linkedin(String SAccount_linkedin) {
  this.SAccount_linkedin = SAccount_linkedin;
  }

  public String getSAccount_twitter() {
  return SAccount_twitter;
  }

  public void setSAccount_twitter(String SAccount_twitter) {
  this.SAccount_twitter = SAccount_twitter;
  }

  public String getSAccount_instagram() {
  return SAccount_instagram;
  }

  public void setSAccount_instagram(String SAccount_instagram) {
  this.SAccount_instagram = SAccount_instagram;
  }

  public String getSAccount_youtube() {
  return SAccount_youtube;
  }

  public void setSAccount_youtube(String SAccount_youtube) {
  this.SAccount_youtube = SAccount_youtube;
  }
  }
  ```
- Code is

  ```
  //Decleration
  private SAccountConnectModel mSAccountConnectModel = new      SAccountConnectModel();
  private ArrayList<SAccountConnectModel> mSAccountConnectModelArrayList = new ArrayList<SAccountConnectModel>();

  //Code
  /*Leader Board Network Connectivity Check and Display only connected network*/
              JSONObject mainObject = null, resultObject = null, userObject = null, userDetailObject = null, sAccountObject = null,
                      fbNetwokObject = null, twNetworkObject = null, igNetworkObject = null, lnNetworkObject = null, ytNetworkObject = null;
              try {
                  mainObject = new JSONObject(response);
                  resultObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("result");
                  if (mainObject != null) {
                      JSONArray dataJsonArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("data");
                      if (dataJsonArray != null) {
                          for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                              Logger.e(TAG, "My Response Data : " + dataJsonArray.get(i));
                              userObject = (JSONObject) dataJsonArray.get(i);
                              if (userObject != null) {
                                  userDetailObject = (JSONObject) userObject.get("user_details");
                                  Logger.e(TAG, "My Response User Details Data : " + userDetailObject);
                                  if (userDetailObject != null) {
                                      sAccountObject = userDetailObject.getJSONObject("saccounts");
                                      Logger.e(TAG, "My Response Social Account Data : " + sAccountObject);
                                      if (sAccountObject != null) {
                                          try {
                                              fbNetwokObject = sAccountObject.getJSONObject("fb");
                                              twNetworkObject = sAccountObject.getJSONObject("tw");
                                              igNetworkObject = sAccountObject.getJSONObject("ig");
                                              lnNetworkObject = sAccountObject.getJSONObject("ln");
                                              ytNetworkObject = sAccountObject.getJSONObject("yt");
                                              if (fbNetwokObject != null)
                                                  mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_facebook("true");
                                              else
                                                  mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_facebook("false");

                                          } catch (JSONException e) {

                                          }
                                          mSAccountConnectModelArrayList.add(i,mSAccountConnectModel);
                                      }
                                      /*if (sAccountObject != null) {
                                          *//*Check Facebook Connection Available or not*//*
                                          if (sAccountObject.getJSONObject("fb") != null)
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_facebook("true");
                                          else
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_facebook("false");
                                          *//*Check LinkedIn Connection Available or not*//*
                                          if (sAccountObject.getJSONObject("ln") != null)
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_linkedin("true");
                                          else
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_linkedin("false");
                                          *//*Check Instagram Connection Available or not*//*
                                          if (sAccountObject.getJSONObject("ig") != null)
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_instagram("true");
                                          else
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_instagram("false");
                                          *//*Check YouTube Connection Available or not*//*
                                          if (sAccountObject.getJSONObject("yt") != null)
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_youtube("true");
                                          else
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_youtube("false");
                                          if (sAccountObject.getJSONObject("tw") != null)
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_twitter("true");
                                          else
                                              mSAccountConnectModel.setSAccount_twitter("false");
                                      }*/
                                  }
                              }

                              Logger.e(TAG, "Model Size is : " + mSAccountConnectModelArrayList.size());
                          }
                      }
                      Logger.e(TAG, "Model Size is : " + mSAccountConnectModelArrayList.size());
                  }
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First check for the key in particular json object using below line.

**for example:**

```
if(sAccountObject.has("fb")){

 fbNetwokObject = sAccountObject.getJSONObject("fb");
}
```

If this isn't your issue then please add the crash report here.

Comment: if  "fb" not available then i set my model class, set_facebook="false" other wise true, how it, is

Comment: just check the key using if(sAccountObject.has("fb")) this condition it will return true if "fb" key is exist and false if key does not exist. so just set your set_facebook according to it. just like.. set_facebook = sAccountObject.has("fb").

Comment: every time sAccountObject, contains first value, not change the sAccountObject value, so what we do,

Comment: I am not getting you properly what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you replace get with opt.

Example
replace 
`twNetworkObject = sAccountObject.getJSONObject("tw");` with 
`twNetworkObject = sAccountObject.optJSONObject("tw");`

[read this for whole documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: i want to display only "saccount" available object on layout

Comment: if "saccount" have 3 network like fb, tw,ln display those icon, if 2 then display related those icon